# TextInputEditText bottom line not show with style

Tags: android

The bottom line of `TextInputEditText`  not show when I add style in `TextInputEditText`

**Before adding Style :**

[image]

**After Adding Style**

[image]

**Here is code :**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:hint="@string/first_name"
            app:counterMaxLength="50">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/cal_gen_title_txt"
                style="@style/InputEditTextStyle"
                android:maxLength="50" />


        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Here is style :**

```
 <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="counterEnabled">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="InputEditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>

    </style>
```

I want show bottom line with using style of `TextInputEditText` thanks

Comment: why are you using a Widget.AppCompat.EditText style ?

Comment: As @GabrieleMariotti mentioned,  you have to set the parent to TextInputEditText in you style so it inherits it's properties from material design

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is part of the views default style, which you are overriding setting your own style.

If you extend your own style from TextInputEditText instead of EditText, it should work.

I think the style of TextInputEditText is Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox, but I might be wrong!